# C++ forcing compilation optimization for variable references to make direct

Tags: c++, reference, ipc

Okay, so I have several processes which share memory blocks. These memory blocks are data structures which have as members objects of the type bar.

```
// in header bar.hpp

struct foo {
  double var1;
  double var2;

  foo() 
    : var1(0.0),
      var2(0.0)
  {}

};


struct bar {

  foo fooArray[5];

  double & var1;
  double & var2;

  bar()
    : fooArray(),
      var1(fooArray[0].var1),
      var2(fooArray[0].var2)
  {}

  bar(const bar& a)
    : fooArray(),
      var1(fooArray[0].var1),
      var2(fooArray[0].var2)
  {*this = a;}

  void operator=(const bar& a) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) fooArray[i] = a.fooArray[i];
  }

};
```

And the shared memory data structure:

```
struct shmType {

  bar data;

};
```

The reason for the references bar::var1 and bar::var2 is that originally the struct bar just had these var1 and var2 as plain data members and no fooArray. It was decided to expand this and put these data in an array. The actual code and extent of the bar struct is quite large, and I really do not want to go into the hundreds of source files and change every barObj.var1 into a barObj.fooArray[0].var1, especially since the name var1 is not unique to the struct bar (so I cannot do a search/replace).

The problem with doing the references is that the internal pointers stored in the bar class to represent these references are not inter-process compatible. If you construct a bar object in the shared memory in one process, then try to access the bar::var1 reference of that object in a different process, you get a seg fault. (which is to be expected)

My question is: is there a way to force the compiler to recognize that bar::var1/var2 are really just aliases to a local sub-struct, so it just "compiles away" the reference? The initializer for bar::var1/2 does not change regardless of how each object is instantiated, so I would assume it's possible, but I have not figured out how to do it.

Comment: So this is a crazy silly thing to ask, and it only demonstrates my lack of understanding of global references in C++11, but try `double && var1;` lol.  I somehow doubt that will be your answer though, and I've just embarrassed myself.

Comment: This is a textbook example in favour of using getters/setters instead of public variables. I'd advise you to refactor and *use accessors* this time: better do it right now than get into further trouble.

Comment: @Aggieboy rvalue references won't help here.

Comment: I am not using C++11.

Comment: @syam The original programs/data structures were written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler, you may be able to use an anonymous `union` along with an anonymous `struct`. **Note that this is not standard C++**, it really depends on your compiler (GCC allows it, I don't know about others) and thus can be quite fragile if you want to write portable code.

```
struct Foo {
  int x, y;
};

struct Bar {
  union {
    Foo fooArray[5];
    struct {
      int x;
      int y;
    }; // warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-pedantic]
  };
};
```

Still, I stand by my comment: the best solution would probably be to refactor the whole thing and use accessors instead of public variables. This will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: I agree that is the best solution and will definitely be implemented in the long run, but right now doing a major change on all the source files is out of the question. Your solution is creative but I feel like omitting the constructor from foo is a step backwards from where we need to be going.

Comment: Well let's hope this anonymous `union/struct` hack can work for you then. Unfortunately it's just duct tape, can't think of anything better.

Comment: Oh, omitting the constructors was just for brevity, I was concentrating on the data structure itself. You can use a constructor in `Bar` as long as it only touches `fooArray`. And of course, you can do what you want in `Foo`.

Comment: I mean the constructor for foo. C++ does not let you use actual classes (e.g. a struct with member functions) inside unions, and the actual Foo class has about a dozen members, so it's very useful to use the constructor.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot C++03 had this restriction, my bad. I guess I'm really getting used to C++11... So I'm afraid refactoring is the only option left that I can think of.